# Simulator Isn't Showing,Rendering Xcode App Project

Tags: xcode, simulator

My Xcode App icon doesn't appear on the simulator screen.

I'm unsure about the cause, though I deleted an app icon on the simulator of a past project, and since, new project app icons aren't appearing.

I closed and opened the simulator several times. The project app isn't appearing.

Comment: What does "rendering an app" mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An Xcode project app isn't rendering in the Xcode Simulator App. The Icon of the App isn't appearing on the simulator app Home Screen.

Comment: My App Icon doesn't appear in the Simulator App.